# Efficient way to extract both unique and duplicate elements from array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I am looking to find an efficient way to extract both unique and duplicate elements from array with identifiable elements in Swift.
Just to make clear there are two points here:

- I need to know both unique and duplicate elements, and just removing the duplicates is not what I need.
- I want to group the duplicate elements by their id

I made the following extension on Array:

```
public extension Array where Element: Identifiable {
    /// A helper to filter duplicate items in an array
    /// - Returns uniquElements: Unique elements in array, considering the first element to be chosen when there are duplicates
    /// - Returns duplicateElementGroups: Duplicate elements in the array grouped by their id
    func filterDuplicates() -> (uniquElements: [Element], duplicateElementGroups: [Element.ID: [Element]]) {
        var uniqueElements = [Element]()
        var uniqueIDs = [Element.ID: Element]()
        var duplicateElements = [Element.ID: [Element]]()
        
        for element in self {
            if let existingDuplicateElement = uniqueIDs[element.id] {
                if let existingDuplicatesArray = duplicateElements[element.id] {
                    duplicateElements[element.id] = existingDuplicatesArray + [element]
                } else {
                    duplicateElements[element.id] = [existingDuplicateElement, element]
                }
            } else {
                uniqueIDs[element.id] = element
                uniqueElements.append(element)
            }
        }
        
        return (uniqueElements, duplicateElements)
    }
}
```

Another solution can be the following, where we store less storage, but we iterate one more time. It is also a bit more readable:

```
func filterDuplicates() -> (uniquElements: [Element], duplicateElementGroups: [Element.ID: [Element]]) {
    var uniqueElements = [Element]()
    var duplicateElements = [Element.ID: [Element]]()
    
    let mapppedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: self, by: \.id)
    
    for element in self {
        if duplicateElements[element.id] == nil {
            uniqueElements.append(element)
        }
        
        if let allValuesForKey = mapppedDictionary[element.id], allValuesForKey.count > 1 {
            duplicateElements[element.id] = allValuesForKey
        }
    }
    
    return (uniqueElements, duplicateElements)
}
```

I also wrote the test to verify it works:

```
// MARK: - Dummy Data
struct SampleIdentifiableElement: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}

func test_whenFilterDuplicatesInArray_uniqueAndDuplicateItemsReturns() {
    // Given
    let sampleElements: [SampleIdentifiableElement] = [
        .init(id: "1", title: "title 1"),
        .init(id: "2", title: "title 2 - first duplicate"),
        .init(id: "2", title: "title 2 - second duplicate"),
        .init(id: "2", title: "title 2 - third duplicate"),
        .init(id: "3", title: "title 3"),
        .init(id: "4", title: "title 4 - first duplicate"),
        .init(id: "4", title: "title 4 - second duplicate")
    ]

    // When
    let (uniquElements, duplicateElementGroups) = sampleElements.filterDuplicates()
            
    // Then
    XCTAssertEqual(uniquElements.count, 4)
    XCTAssertEqual(duplicateElementGroups.count, 2)
    XCTAssertEqual(duplicateElementGroups["2"]?.count, 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(duplicateElementGroups["4"]?.count, 2)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(duplicateElementGroups["2"]?.first?.title, "title 2 - first duplicate")
    XCTAssertEqual(duplicateElementGroups["2"]?.last?.title, "title 2 - third duplicate")
            
    XCTAssertEqual(uniquElements.first?.title, "title 1")
    XCTAssertEqual(uniquElements.last?.title, "title 4 - first duplicate")
}
```

I wonder how to make more efficient way in terms of time and space complexity?

Currently both have the time complexity of O(n) and space complexity of O(n). However, in the first solution we iterate once through all items, while we store more data. The second one takes less space, but we iterate one more time.

Comment: You can replace most of this code with just a simple `Dictionary(grouping: self, by: \.id)`. From there, and derive the return values from that

Comment: @Alexander Thank you. I was thinking about that too, but that needs 3 times of iteration through all elements: 
(1) map the array to dictionary with key to be ID. 
(2) iterate again for having them grouped by ID: Dictionary(grouping: self, by: \.id)
(3) iterate again through grouped dictionary to took duplicate and unique elements out of it.
However, now there is only one time of iteration through all elements

Comment: Soheil you asked about complexity. Your solution is optimal regarding time complexity. The dictionary grouping would be as well. The difference you point out is only a constant factor, so it will not matter to the complexity. It may matter in practice, though :)

Comment: Without measurements, this would be a fruitless conversation. It's a mistake to think that it would be slower to iterating something several times instead of just once. Sure you lower your iteration overhead (maintaining loop counters and whatever), but you're also making each iteration longer, probably causing the CPU cache performance to be worse. And it's unlikely that the optimizer will merge the loops (if worthwhile), anyway. It all comes down to profiling.

Comment: @Alexander I added the solution you convey as well in the question. Going to measure them. Thank you again

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard In your second snippet, I don't think `uniqueElements` is computed correctly. `duplicateElements[element.id] == nil` will never be true. You don't need the loop either. This just boiled down to `let uniqueElements = mapppedDictionary.values.filter { $0.count == 1 }` and `let duplicateElements = uniqueElements.filter { id, group in 1 < group.count }`. Also also, `mappedDictionary` is a bad name (it's not mapped, it's grouped, and the fact that it's a dict is obvious. So it's half wrong, half useless :D ). Consider `elementedByID`

Comment: It's because filter will do twice the loop, but indeed, it should be: `mapppedDictionary.forEach { if $0.value.count > 1 { duplicateElements[$0.key] = $0.value } else { uniqueElements.append($0.value) } }` (or something like that, not tested), but I'd use a `reduce(into:_:)`, as a personal preference.